# What can I do with red chests, doors and crystals?

Tags: neon-abyss

Once they get damaged, purple chests, doors and crystals become red and hurtful.

Is it possible to do anything with it?  I tried shooting them and exploding them, but without any visible result.

[image: red chest]
[image: red crystal]
[image: red door]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So these "devil" (red and spiky) props are "guardian" (purple crystal) props that received damages.
While interacting with guardian props requires to spend crystals and fills up the guardian gauge (down right corner of the screen), interacting with devil props costs life (can be hearts or shields) and fills up the devil gauge.

A full guardian gauge gives access to the guardian room (via teleporter) where you can choose between two items for free.

[image: guardian gauge]

A full devil gauge opens the devil room where sacrificing a heart slot allows you to choose between three items.

[image: devil gauge]

Comment: I can't test right now, but it seemed to me that you can only fill one gauge at a time. And doing an action for the other gauge (than the current one) had no effect. For instance, paying a crystal to a floating purple crystal while filling the devil gauge looks like a waste of a crystal.

Comment: Guardian props will slowly reduce your devil gauge, and devil props will very quickly reset your guardian gauge.

Answer (score 1):

According to [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NeonAbyss/comments/hn37k7/anyone_know_how_to_unlock_or_obtain_the_red/), you can walk into the red spiked chests, sacrificing health to make them openable once more.